# What is the layout/draw time threshold 90/120Hz Android devices?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-view, android-screen-support

I want my app to perform all of its transitions and animations smoothly across devices.  We are told in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/performance) article that we should keep the drawing time under 16ms to keep the UI "buttery smooth".  I am wondering if this is a good target for 90/120Hz devices as well, and if not, what magic number should I be aiming to get under?  Granted most of these devices are pretty powerful (at the moment) but with complex animations things can still become jittery from time to time.

Comment: There's 1000 ms in 1 second. 1000/60=16.6, 1000/90=11.1, 1000/120=8.3, and so on.

Comment: Happens to everyone :D